# Black screen appears on click of a button before navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

[image]I have a sign in page with 2 text fields for username, password and a button. Once you click on that button, it takes you to a view controller. There is a navigation controller in between that viewcontroller and the signincontroller.

For some reason, I get this black screen. Yesterday deleting a segue or a element on the storyboard would stop it from happening but now its consistently happening.

If I kill the running app, click on the app icon to load it again then it shows the signincontroller as expected. But initially this keeps happening.

I'm not sure what to do exactly.

I also tried to "Reset content and settings" and it still did not work.

My flow is:
`SigninVC push-> NavigationController -> ViewController` (no connection between navigationcontroller and viewcontroller as signinviewcontroller's button "signin" performs the segue:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signin_success", sender: self)`
[image]

[Update] Also please note I tried removing NavigationController completely and it does not give me that black screen anymore although there is now a white screen appearing before it loads the signinviewcontroller

Comment: Do you present it modaly or with push ?

Comment: with push @SvetoslavBramchev

Comment: u r going to that vc using push?

Comment: @elk_cloner yeah

Comment: no connection then why navigation controller?

Comment: could u pls provide a pic of ur storyboard?

Comment: @elk_cloner thanks for helping, attached a pic

Answer (score 0):

Just add your navigation controller before every other controller and show navigation bar where you need and remove it where you do not need it.
If you can not make it please send me your test project and I will make it for you :)

Comment: Is that good practice though? I thought there should 1 navigation controller for all the view controllers than every view controller having it's own navigation controller?

Comment: No it is good practice to have new navigation controller for every new storyboard point but have only one navigation controller for viewcontrollers in one storyboard

Comment: your comment is confusing, can you please elaboraate